# Custom UITextField class only applied to first text field

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have made my first custom class in Swift and I want to use it for the text fields in my app. The problem is that it only works for the first textfield in the view controller, the class is not applied to the second one (the second one has no rounded corners, default placeholder color etc.). I have double checked that the right "custom class" is set in the storyboard for both textfields. Why isn't the class applied to both fields? Seems like a thing with a simple solution but I haven't found any...

Here is the class:

```
import UIKit


class RoundedUITextField: UITextField {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)

      self.setAttributes()
  }



  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

      super.init(coder: aDecoder)

  }

  func setAttributes() {
      self.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
      let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: self.frame.height))
      self.leftView = paddingView
      self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
      self.textColor = UIColor.white
      self.alpha = 0.7
      let str = NSAttributedString(string: (self.placeholder)!, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white])
      self.attributedPlaceholder = str



  }

}
```

Here is the view controller code:

```
class LogInViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var password: RoundedUITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userName: RoundedUITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    userName.setAttributes()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I discovered now that the problem lies in the "setAttributes", I thought the attributes where set in the class but they're actually only set in viewDidLoad for one of them (I put it there in the beginning and forgot to remove it)... I want this to be done in the "init" of the class for all of the fields...

Comment: post your IBOutlets definitions code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `self.setAttributes()` in your `awakeFromNib` method and remove it from `init(frame: CGRect)`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setAttributes()
}
```

**your custom class code will be like this**

```
import UIKit


class RoundedUITextField: UITextField {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
  }



  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setAttributes()
}

  func setAttributes() {
      self.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
      let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: self.frame.height))
      self.leftView = paddingView
      self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
      self.textColor = UIColor.white
      self.alpha = 0.7
      let str = NSAttributedString(string: (self.placeholder)!, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white])
      self.attributedPlaceholder = str



  }

}
```

Hope this helps